# node.js call function from google map api(javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

How nodejs call function from google map api(javascript)?

I wish you can explain to me with some examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps for that. You can find examples on the github page.